# How do I use CSS to keep multiple images relatively sized withing the same outer element?

Tags: css, image, resize

I've seen several posts about how to auto-size a single image within an outer element. All these solutions seem to do this by making the image width 100%. But I need to stack several images side by side, each image having height equivalent to the outer element height put maintaining relative width. I tried doing image height=100% but that doesn't seem to work.

In my case, the outer element is a div set to a relative position within an outer div.

```
<div class="basicskin thumb">
    <img class="background" src="/content/skinz/SolidBack/240px/SolidBack-sml_grn.png">
    <div class="numbers" style="top: 14.8571428571429%; left: 6.46666666666667%; height: 68.8253968253968%; width: 87.2444444444444%;">
        <img../><img../>
    </div>
</div>
```

The styles look like this:

```
div.basicskin
{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.basicskin.thumb > img.background
{
    height: 32px;
    width: auto;
}

div.basicskin > div.numbers
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.basicskin > div.numbers img
{
width:auto;
position:relative;
}
```

My images want to render full size instead of relative to my "numbers" div.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I see you like using % sizes a lot. I hope you know what you are doing because in case you didn't notice this thing can make your site look completely different in different screen resolutions and browsers.

Comment: Not particularly. For this application I just don't see any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set `height: 100%;` to the `<img/>`, you should make it `display: block;` and give some `height` to the parent block.

`height: 100%;` works only when it's parent has set `height`.

**For IE** `inline-block` support you can use this fix:

```
.selector {
    display: inline-block;
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
```

Comment: But if I make each img display-block then the images won't line up next to each other, right? How would I overcome that?

Comment: You can also use `float: left;` or (`display: inline-block;` with `vertical-align: top;`) to make images line up. Note that IE8 and lower versions does not support `display: inline-block;`. Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to % can be tricky, because your element is inside `<body>` and `<html>` that *may not be with 100% height* unlike you may be instinctively assuming. You have to set those elements height to 100% too to make sure you can expand things to the full vertical extension of the screen. I also recommend you head your html file with `<!doctype html>` to make sure those things work correctly in every browser.